# Replacing Sisense Smart Label Widget With Blox Widgets

Tags: sisense

I am trying to learn Sisense Blox. I watched the videos and looked at the docs but am still unclear how to replace a specific Smart Label Widget with Blox.

Below is the widget and config. Is there a Blox Template that I could use to recreate this widget? If not, how can I use the [documentation](https://documentation.sisense.com/latest/blox/bloxreference.htm#gsc.tab=0) to figure this out:

[image]

[image]

If someone could point me to some Blox JSON examples to get this working it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this template allows you to inject a pure html snippet into a BloX widget. To use your fields, simply add {panel: FieldName} to the html.

In your case it would be something like:

```
{"style": "",
"script": "",
"title": "",
"showCarousel": true,
"body": [
    {
        "type": "Container",
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "id": "",
                "class": "",
                "text": "<p>{panel:Location Source}</p><p>{panel:Destination}</p>"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```